# How can i increase the search display rate of my app in Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play

I published my first app to the Android Market an have the weird problem, that it cannot be found, except I search for its name. It does not appear in the published category list, it does not show up, if I search for the words included in its description. I tested it with my phone, which has Android 2.3.5 installed. My definitions in the manifest file:

```
package="info.appcube.tatra"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In the Android Developer Console I see, that it will be available for 1103 devices. In the Developer Console I added two languages (english and german). This is my english description:

"Get your world organized with Tatra!

Create tasks or to-do lists, add pictures, contacts, categories and notes to them. Let Tatra remind you, based on time and location."

Is this a configuration issue? How long does it take normally, until the app is searchable by its description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your application's download statistics and ratings etc.If your application gets a good trend and a good download/rating ratio it'll be soon listed in related category view.

Also the same for search results if the app gets a good trend it'll be showed on the top of the search query and will not need exact name.You need some time for that.